# Authenticating Google Drive Request

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

End Goal: I want to redirect to a Google Drive api link to allow the user to download files.
Ex: http://example.com/redirect -->  https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<FILE ID>?alt=media  --> File Downloads for User

I am trying to redirect users to a drive api link where files can be downloaded, but to do this the request must be authenticated. I know this can be done through authorization header but as we all know it's not possible to send headers with a redirect. If it helps I am using the fastify web framework.

Comment: What happens if you set the file to public?  #justcurious

Comment: Still says it needs authentication.

Comment: Yeah i think your going to be out of luck, your going to have to grant the user access to the file.  There's no way around that.    Drive isn't meant to be a file hosting service, stuff like this used to be possible but Google has locked it down.

Comment: Hm okay guess its not possible with a redirect, the file downloads fine when the auth header is provided. [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) it says "It is possible to send tokens as URI query-string parameters, but we don't recommend it, because URI parameters can end up in log files that are not completely secure", obviously this isnt secure but I'm curious how this would be done.

Answer (score 0):

For the fun of it i just tried something like this, which basically just adds the access token to the end of the request.  No dice there either.

```
const access = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token
window.location.assign('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1v8QrAOxyC_5LQNovaq9XNALvnDocKeF6HxrrHPyWwRU?alt=media&access_token='+ access);
```

[image]

Comment: Yup I've tried this, with no luck. Same error. If you look [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) though it says its possible to authenticate through a uri parameter, it just doesn't say how.

Comment: sending access_token= in the query string is the accepted method to authorize though the url.  Ok so why does it work with the webContentLink?  Google must add something to that that will bypass that protection.

Comment: webContentLink is not what I'm looking for. The webContentLink isn't a direct download link for files >25MB. This is due to google's automatic virus scan I believe.

Comment: I'm trying to use the web content link by grabbing the confirm code. But when doing this and providing the access token it still prompts to sign in. any ideas?

Comment: Drive really isn't meant to be a hosting service they kill that years ago

Comment: Ah okay, well I guess I'll have to look for alternatives